# Python using apply function to skip Nan

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, apply, nan

I am trying to preprocess a dataset to use for XGBoost by mapping the classes in each column to numerical values. A working example looks like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ['A', 'B','C','B','A'], 'col2': ['Z', 'X','Z','Z','Y'], 'col3':['I','J','I','J','J']})
d = defaultdict(LabelEncoder)
encodedDF = df1.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))
inv = encodedDF.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].inverse_transform(x))
```

Where encodedDF gives the output:

```
col1 col2 col3
 0    2    0
 1    0    1
 2    2    0
 1    2    1
 0    1    1
```

And inv just reverts it back to the original dataframe. My issue is when null values get introduced:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ['A', 'B',None,'B','A'], 'col2': ['Z', 'X','Z',None,'Y'], 'col3':['I','J','I','J','J']})
encodedDF = df2.apply(lambda x: d[x.name].fit_transform(x))
```

Running the above will throw the error:

"TypeError: ('argument must be a string or number', 'occurred at index col1')"

Basically, I want to apply the encoding, but skip over the individual cell values that are null to get an output like this:

```
col1 col2 col3
0     2    0
1     0    1
NaN   2    0
1     NaN  1
0     1    1
```

I can't use dropna() before applying the encoding because then I lose data that I will be trying to impute down the line with XGBoost. I can't use conditionals to skip x if null, (e.g. using x.notnull() in the lambda function) because fit_transform(x) uses a Pandas.Series object as the argument, and none of the logical operators that I could use in the conditional appear to do what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure what else to try in order to get this to work. I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense. Let me know if I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a workaround. I probably should have been using sklearn's OneHotEncoder class from the beginning instead of the LabelEncoder/defaultdict combo. I'm brand new to all this. I replaced NaNs with dummy values, and then dropped those dummy values once I encoded the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ['A', 'B','C',None,'A'], 'col2': ['Z', 'X',None,'Z','Y'], 'col3':['I','J',None,'J','J'], 'col4':[45,67,None,32,94]})

replaceVals = {'col1':'missing','col2':'missing','col3':'missing','col4':-1}
df = df.fillna(value = replaceVals,axis=0)

drop = [['missing'],['missing'],['missing'],[-1]]
enc = OneHotEncoder(drop=drop)
encodeDF = enc.fit_transform(df)
```